# Find min/max of numpy array excluding zeros along an axis

Tags: python, numpy

There is a nice way of finding the nonzero min/max of an array excluding zeros described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164397/find-the-min-max-excluding-zeros-in-a-numpy-array-or-a-tuple-in-python):

```
import numpy as np
minval = np.min(a[np.nonzero(a)])
maxval = np.max(a[np.nonzero(a)])
```

However, this won't work as soon as `a` is a 2- or more dimensional array and an axis for the min/max is desired. Any simple solutions for that?

Comment: How close to zero is still zero if you are considering reals? A potentially important point to consider as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a *non*-vectorised approach. It can be vectorised by setting 0 values to `a.min()` / `a.max()` as separate steps.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 0],
              [3, 1, 9],
              [0, 3, 4]])

minval = np.min(np.where(a==0, a.max(), a), axis=0)
# array([ 1.,  1.,  4.])

maxval = np.max(np.where(a==0, a.min(), a), axis=0)
# array([ 3.,  3.,  9.])
```

Comment: Set to `a.min(axis= )` and `a.max(axis= )` instead of Infs for keeping the dtypes.

Comment: `np.min(np.where(a==0, a.max(), a), axis=0)` or `np.min(np.where(a==0, a.max(axis=0), a), axis=0)`. Similarly for the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Masked arrays are designed exactly for these kind of purposes. You can leverage masking zeros from array (or ANY other kind of mask you desire) and do pretty much most of the stuff you do on regular arrays on your masked array now:

```
import numpy.ma as ma
mx = ma.masked_array(x, mask=x==0)
mx.min(1)
```

Example input:

```
x = np.array([[3., 2., 0., 1., 6.], [8., 4., 5., 0., 6.], [0., 7., 2., 5., 0.]])
```

output:

```
[1.0 4.0 2.0]
```